# Launching executing a file using hta / html

Tags: html, button, exe, hta

I have this code:

```
<body background = "Image.png">

<body>
<input type="button" value="Option 1" name="run_button"  onClick="TestSub"><p>
<input type="button" value="Option 2" name="run_button"  onClick="TestSub"><p> 
<input type="button" value="Option 3" name="run_button"  onClick="TestSub"><p> 
<input type="button" value="Option 4" name="run_button"  onClick="TestSub"><p> 
<input type="button" value="Option 5" name="run_button"  onClick="TestSub"><p> 
<input type="button" value="Option 6" name="run_button"  onClick="TestSub"><p> 
<input type="button" value="Option 7" name="run_button"  onClick="TestSub"><p> 
<input type="button" value="Option 8" name="run_button"  onClick="TestSub"><p> 
<input type="button" value="Option 9" name="run_button"  onClick="TestSub"><p> 
<input type="button" value="Option 10" name="run_button"  onClick="TestSub"><p> 
</body>
```

When i run it it comes up with 10 buttons but my questions is how do i get it to launch a program called test.exe when the first button is pressed

Comment: [`WshShell.Run()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) is probably what you're looking for?

Comment: Tried that but I get a WshShell is not defined error

Comment: you should show what you've tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an ActiveX like so:

```
var shell = new ActiveXObject('WScript.Shell');
shell.Run(strCommand, intWindowStyle, bWaitOnReturn);
```

Please read the MSDN article about [`Run()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) to populate the arguments.

Comment: @09stephenb: you haven't posted any script

Comment: @Dr.Molle At the very top of the post there is a big piece of code